# how to change the size of a hyperlink - image field

Tags: office-365

I have a custom list with a hyperlink or picture field that I want to show as image, but I want to control the size of the image, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have access to sharepoint designer, you can access the code for your webpage, and possibly modify it from there.  The easiest way I can think of doing it is to go to the page that shows the images using Google Chrome, do the element inspection on the image, and figure out how images are classed.  Make your changes accordingly in the web code.